# Django Object Log

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application and I'm adding a Django log Object to it.  Based on this documentation:

https://code.osuosl.org/projects/django-object-log/wiki/Usage#Registering-Action-Types

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-object-log/0.6#downloads

I am in the process of creating templates for action types.  Where should I insert the following html code?

```
 {# sample template for MY_EVENT #}
 {{log_item.user.username}} did something interesting to {{log_item.object1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's for the template you are providing to `LogAction.objects.register`